# Erro conversão de Char para String

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
procedure TDM_Maquinas.IBQCons_MaquinasCOD_LINHAGetText(Sender: TField;
var Text: string; DisplayText: Boolean);
begin
  Text := Sender.AsString;
  if Text <> '' then
  begin
    case Text[1] of
    '1'   : Text := 'Linha 1';
    '2'   : Text := 'Linha 2';
    '3'   : Text := 'Linha 3';
    '4'   : Text := 'Linha 4';
    '101' : Text := 'Recebimento 1'; //aqui da erro
    '102' : Text := 'Recebimento 2'; //aqui da erro
    '201' : Text := 'Expedição 1';   //aqui da erro
    '202' : Text := 'Expedição 2';   //aqui da erro
    '203' : Text := 'Expedição 3';   //aqui da erro
   end;
 end;
end;
```

error:

```
E2010 Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'string'
```

Como faço para resolver?

Comment: Como poderia Text[1] ser igual a 101,102.....?

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo, por que não poderia ser ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao analisar o padrão, temos que os cases são sempre números, então, poderíamos converter o valor do Text para `integer`, e assim solucionar seu problema:

```
procedure TDM_Maquinas.IBQCons_MaquinasCOD_LINHAGetText(Sender: TField;
var Text: string; DisplayText: Boolean);
begin
  Text := Sender.AsString;
  if Text <>'' then
  begin
    case StrToInt(Text) of
    1   : Text := 'Linha 1';
    2   : Text := 'Linha 2';
    3   : Text := 'Linha 3';
    4   : Text := 'Linha 4';
    101 : Text := 'Recebimento 1'; 
    102 : Text := 'Recebimento 2'; 
    201 : Text := 'Expedição 1';   
    202 : Text := 'Expedição 2';   
    203 : Text := 'Expedição 3';   
   end;
 end;
end;
```

Edit: Assim como o @Reginaldo comentou, ao utilizar o Text[1], terá somente o primeiro caractere da sua string, então também alterei Text[1] por Text

Comment: Se Text[1] tem apenas um caracter. Como pode StrToInt(Text[1]) ser igual a 101,102..?

Comment: Viajei aqui, pensei que o `text` era um vetor, e ele tava pegando a primeira posição para usar no case. Então trocando o `Text[1]` por `Text`, resolve o problema. Obrigado @ReginaldoRigo